# Batch File to Find Filenames

Tags: search, batch-file, find

Is it possible to create a batch file which searches all sub folders for a specific string in all the file names?

For example it could be searching for "2013" contained within the file name?

Is it then possible to create a text file list of all the files which contain the search term "2013"?

Answer (score 1):

```
dir c:\*2013* /s /b /a-d > 2013list.txt
```